# The code doesn't gives me any output in Dev-C++

Tags: c++, arrays, dev-c++

When I try to run this code in Dev-C++. There is no output. But when I run it in any online compiler, the code runs smoothly. Why it is not running in Dev-C++?

I have tried running it in various online compilers, where it is running smoothly.

```
int main()
{
    int T;
    cin>>T;
    while(T--)
    {
        long long int N, K;
        cin>>N>>K;
        long long int arr[N];
        for(long long i=0; i<N; i++)
        {
            cin>>arr[i];
        }

        long long int max = INT_MIN;
        long long int dp[N];

        for(int i=N-1; i>=0; i--)
        {
            if((i+K)>=N)
            {
                dp[i] = arr[i];
            }

            else
            {
                dp[i] = (dp[i+K]+ arr[i]);
            }
        }

        for(int k=0; k<N; k++)
        {
            if (dp[k]>max)
            {
                max = dp[k];
            }
        }
        cout<<max<<endl;
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `long long int arr[N];` is not legal in standard `c++` and this actually may be the reason for why it does not work. Remember the stack is usually limited to 1 MB on windows. However the default stack on linux is 10 MB.

Comment: `long long int arr[N];` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have the number of entries determined by a compile-time expression, not a variable.  Use `std::vector<long long> arr(N);` instead.

Comment: *But when I run it in any online compiler* --  [Not this one](https://rextester.com/GZO56407), for the reasons already pointed out in the previous comments.

Comment: "Dev-C++" Now that's a name I've not heard in a long time... I recommend using a newer, better IDE. Bloodshed Dev-C++ hasn't been updated in 14 years, and even Orwell Dev-C++ hasn't been updated in over 2 years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take a look at this line of the code:

```
long long int arr[N];
```

Because `N` isn't a compile-time constant, you're trying to create what's known asa variable-length array. Variable length arrays are valid in newer versions of C, but not in C++. It *does* compile under GCC as a non-standard extension, which is probably why it compiled on the online compiler.

We can do what you want just by using a vector (from `#include <vector>`)

```
std::vector<long long int> arr(N); //Create a vector of size N
```

You can use a vector in the exact same way you'd use an array.

Comment: What do you mean by 'newer versions of C'?  Neither C nor C++ permit this kind of declaration.

Comment: By newer versions of C, I *mean* newer versions of C. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array#Variable-length_arrays

Answer (score 0):

MAy be due to `long long int arr[N];` its not acceptable in DEV C++
Use `std::vector<long long> arr(N);`instead of it.

In DEV C++ 5.11 version it  easily give output

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>


using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int T;


    cin>> T;
    while(T--)
    {
        long long int N, K;
        cin>>N>>K;
        long long int arr[N];
        for(long long i=0; i<N; i++)
        {
            cin>>arr[i];
        }

        long long int max = INT_MIN;
        long long int dp[N];

        for(int i=N-1; i>=0; i--)
        {
            if((i+K)>=N)
            {
                dp[i] = arr[i];
            }

            else
            {
                dp[i] = (dp[i+K]+ arr[i]);
            }
        }

        for(int k=0; k<N; k++)
        {
            if (dp[k]>max)
            {
                max = dp[k];
            }
        }
        cout<<max<<endl;
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```